# Binary data in UITableView cause high CPU Load and freezing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, binary-data

I have some HTML data which I store it in CoreData as `Binary Data`. I display it as `NSMutableAttributedString` in `UITableViewCells` as below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSManagedObject *row = [self.messagesFRC objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    MessageLTableViewCell *cell = (MessageLTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MSGCELLID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *messageText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[row valueForKey:@"message_text"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    messageText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style>body{font-family: '%@';direction:rtl;float:right; font-size:%fpx;}</style>%@", FONT_TEXT, 17.0, messageText];

    NSError *err = nil;
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
      initWithData:[messageText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
      options:
      @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
        NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
    }
    documentAttributes: nil
    error: &err];


    if(err)
        NSLog(@"Unable to parse label text: %@", err);
    cell.messageText.attributedText = attrStr;


    return cell;

}
```

The problem is that it causes high CPU load and also the `UITableView` freezes in scrolling. What is the best practice solutions to handle it with best performance?

Comment: Why are you storing it binary if you then need to convert it to html and then attributed string? So much runtime work for every cell...

Comment: @Wain I need to store it in CoreData, and I could not find any proper type other than the "Binary Data" for it, what do you recommend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should have this logic in your managed object subclass. This kind of heavy lifting with data manipulation does not belong in a table view data source. Give your managed object subclass a convenience method `attributedString` for this.

Second, you can store the HTML as text, i.e. `String` type. This will have the added advantage that it will become searchable.

As for performance, it seems that the data method with `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` is really very slow (someone mentions a test in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18886718/427083)). The alternative is to use `NSRange`s which is feasible if the HTML strings are not too complicated.

Comment: Thanks, I could not store as `String` type, due to I have long text and `String` is very limited.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There are no real limits to the string length in SQLite, certainly not in the dimension of what you would display in a UITableViewCell.  The general advise for too long strings is to break them up somehow (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10327081/427083)).

Comment: Or store in a file and display in a web view. As said long text and table cells don't go well together really...

Comment: @Mundi Could you explain more about "First" in your answer? Any good example is appreciated. I understood the two others and they are useful. Thanks.

Comment: It is simply about code organization. You should enforce the principle of encapsulation, meaning that functionality should be split up and assigned to the units where it belongs. In order to *reuse* the database-to-attributed-text functionality it needs to be part of the managed object. Otherwise you would have to copy-paste your extraction code to the next view controller that wants to use it, making it impossible to maintain after a while.